# My Indian visa has no photograph but my partner's visa does

Tags: visas, india

I have just printed out our Indian e-Visas, the ones with the coat of arms on them. My e-Visa does not have my photograph printed on it, but my partner's does. I can't understand why, as we did our visas in exactly the same way with photo upload, and both our photos show on the form print out. I'm worried that something is wrong. Is this going to cause a problem?

Comment: Does it contain your passport number? If yes, do not bother.

Comment: I've had an Indian visa without a photograph and had no problems although I only have anecdotal evidence

Answer (score 1):

According to @Lassi:

> I've had an Indian visa without a photograph and had no problems although I only have anecdotal evidence

Relax and enjoy your vacation.